# Copying local postgresql to AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a Postgesql database that I want to copy/replicate from my local machine to an AWS RDS instance.

I've created a dump as follows:

```
pg_dump -v -U postgres mydb > mydb.dump
```

I then tried to copy to my RDS as follows:

```
psql -f mydb.dump -h XXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U postgres -d mydb
```

However, I get the following error:

```
psql:mydb.dump:1: error: invalid command \
psql:mydb.dump:6: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ÿ_"
LINE 1: ÿ_-"\o""edrp\nou"tnsctme  e
        ^
```

I then tried to rule out any issues with RDS by copying the archive to another local database as follows:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d mydbcopy mydb.dump
```

I received an error:

```
pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

I also tried the preceding as follows:

```
psql -f my.dump -U postgres -d mydbcopy
```

And got the same error as before:

```
psql:mydb.dump:1: error: invalid command \
psql:mydb.dump:6: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ÿ_"
LINE 1: ÿ_-"\o""edrp\nou"tnsctme  e
        ^
```

I am using Windows Powershell and Postgresql 13.2.

Am I missing something ?

It seems to be an issue with PSQL tools in view that I'm getting the error even when trying to copy locally.

Comment: I now see that it works only when I run pg_dump from the system command prompt, instead of from Powershell. It also creates a dump file about half the size. Can anyone elaborate as to what Powershell is doing ?

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by using

```
pg_dump -f dump.sql --inserts mydb
```

It turns out using the redirect ">" means PowerShell does the file writing and it uses UTF16 which doesn't play nice with psql. The -f flag makes pg_dump do the writing itself.